# How I can get a query parameter value from my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following markup, inside my create form:-

```
<form method="post" action="./NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3a%2f%2fwww.******.intra%2fOrderManagement%2fLists%2fOrderManagement%2fAllItems.aspx&amp;
ContentTypeId=0x0103006FFC142316C0B148896E3C32099B654E0100C4125A72ABD48B46AEB7AB17A2E53735&amp;RootFolder=%2fOrderManagement%2fLists%2fOrderManagement" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

now I am not sure how I can get the value of the `ContentTypeId` parameter inside the `action` attribute for a form which have id =`aspnetForm`?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:

```js
console.log(
  unescape($('#aspnetForm').attr('action'))
  .split('?').pop().split('&')
  .reduce(function(o, e){
    p = e.split('=');
    o[p[0]] = p[1];
    return o;
   }, {})
  .ContentTypeId
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="./NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3a%2f%2fwww.******.intra%2fOrderManagement%2fLists%2fOrderManagement%2fAllItems.aspx&amp;ContentTypeId=0x0103006FFC142316C0B148896E3C32099B654E0100C4125A72ABD48B46AEB7AB17A2E53735&amp;RootFolder=%2fOrderManagement%2fLists%2fOrderManagement" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```